# How to get details of a package in Ubuntu?

Tags: c, shell, ubuntu

I am looking for similar command in Ubuntu which can give complete details about packages like "rpm -qi package name". I need to check installation date, release date, architecture etc.

Above command give output in blow format:

**rpm -qi tracker-miner-firefox-0.12.5-3.4.1.i586**

Name        : tracker-miner-firefox

Version     : 0.12.5

Release     : 3.4.1

Architecture: i586

Install Date: Fri 17 Oct 2014 20:50:18 IST

Group       : System/GUI/GNOME

Size        : 20570

License     : GPLv2+

Signature   : RSA/SHA256, Sun 30 Oct 2011 12:45:33 IST, Key ID b88b2fd43dbdc284

Source RPM  : tracker-extras-0.12.5-3.4.1.src.rpm

Build Date  : Sun 30 Oct 2011 12:44:50 IST

Build Host  : build08

Relocations : (not relocatable)

Packager    : http://bugs.opensuse.org

Vendor      : openSUSE

URL         : http://projects.gnome.org/tracker/

Summary     : Tracker miner to index Firefox bookmarks

Description :
Tracker is a powerful desktop-neutral first class object
database, tag/metadata database, search tool and indexer.
This package contains a Firefox extension that will index
Firefox bookmarks.

Distribution: openSUSE 12.1

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer

```
apt-cache show <package>
```

or

```
dpkg-deb --info <deb_file>
```

Comment: Thanks :) but it don't display installation date.